# memoization vs. state-free code

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, clojurescript

In the development of a stateless Clojure library I encounter a problem: Many functions have to be called repeatedly with the same arguments. Since everything until now is side-effect-free, this will always lead to the same results. I'm considering ways to make this more performative.

---

My library works like this: Every time a function is called it needs to be passed a state-hash-map, the function returns a replacement with a manipulated state object. So this keeps everything immutable and every sort of state is kept outside of the library.

```
(require '[mylib.core :as l])
(def state1 (l/init-state))
(def state2 (l/proceed state1))
(def state3 (l/proceed state2))
```

If proceed should not perform the same operations repeatedly, I have several options to solve this:

---

**Option 1: "doing it by hand"**

Store the necessary state in the state-hash-map, and update only where it is necessary. Means: Having a sophisticated mechanism that knows which parts have to be recalculated, and which not. This is always possible, in my case it would be not that trivial. If I implemented this, I'd produce much more code, which in the end is more error prone. So is it necessary?

**Option 2: memoize**

So there is the temptation to use the `memoize` function at the critical points in the lib: At the points, at which I'd expect the possibility of repeated function calls with the same args. This is sort of another philosophy of programming: Modelling each step as if it was the first time it has to run. And separating the fact that is called several times to another implementation. (this reminds me of the idea of react/om/reagent's render function)

**Option 3: core.memoize**

But memoization is stateful - of course. And this - for example - becomes a problem when the lib runs in a web-server. The server would just keep on filling memory with captured results. In my case however it would make sense, to only capture calculated results for each user-session. So it would be perfect to attach the cache to the previously described state-hash-map, which will be passed back by lib.

And it looks like core.memoize provides some tools for this job. Unfortunately it's not that well documented - I don't really find useful information related to the the described situation.

---

My question is: Do I more or less estimate the possible options correctly? Or are there other options that I have not considered? If not, it looks like the core.memoize is the way to go. Then, I'd appreciate if someone could give me a short pattern at hand, which one should use here.

Answer (score 1):

If `state1`, `state2` & `state3` are different in your example, memoization will gain you nothing. `proceed` would, be called with different arguments each time.

As a general design principle **do not impose caching strategies to the consumer**. Design so that the consumers of your library have the possibility to use whatever memoization technique, or no memoization at all.

---

Also, you don't mention if `init-state` is side-effect free, and if it returns the same `state1`. If that is so, why not just keep all (or some) states as static literals. If they don't take much space, you can write a macro that calculates them compile time. Say, first 20 states hard-coded, then call `proceed`.

Comment: Oh sorry, maybe that was not clear enough. I would not memoize proceed directly, rather inside of proceed there would be calls to memoized subfunctions, which operate on parts(!) of the state. got me?

Comment: init-state is like the rest of the lib side-effect free. so it always return the same thing. i could call it get-initial-state

Comment: If stateX's are always the same, then I suggest going the data way. Also, if you post your code you can get better feedback. Is this a proprietary project?

Comment: Inside 'state', some parts are changed by proceed, others are kept as they are. State2, state3, they are always different, since there's a random inside proceed (arrh, is this still purely functional? I guess not, just realizing..).  The code is just to be build, would not make sense to post it now - but it's not propriatory at all, just private pleasue ;-)

Comment: Random? Not functional anymore. You can pass a seed to init, and use a RNG with that seed (as a lazy-seq on state maybe) (even now some will argue it's not FP). Always post code, even pseudo-code, so we don't have to fish details out.

Comment: @AntonHarald If init-state always returns the same thing, why is it a function? Just `(def init-state {...})`.